# How can I convert a fully qualified file path to URL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a complete file path (`/var/www/project/public/csv/Info.csv`) stored in a variable **$file**

How can I convert this variable into a server friendly URL. I tried to use the `url($file)` helper function but it returns http://127.0.0.1/var/www/soccer/public/csv/Info.csv

The expected output is: http://127.0.0.1/csv/Info.csv

One approach is to cut the string from public and pass it to `url()` function. Does anyone have a more eloquent approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
str_replace(public_path(), '', $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try explode and use asset like this

```
$file = '/var/www/project/public/csv/Info.csv';
$file = explode('/public/', $file);
echo asset($file[1]); 
 Or Manually prepare path
echo config('app.url') . $file[1];

Both ways you can get excepted output http://127.0.0.1/csv/Info.csv
```